# Convert HTML table to table on terminal in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert below HTML table to table display on terminal in python

```
Variables   Details
UserName    XYZ
Email Address   xyz@example.com
Department  Finance
Login Name  xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the content of the table from HTML using a parser such as `BeautifulSoup` and store it into a list. Use a module such as `tabulate` ([link](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate)) to display the information in a table.

Comment: I dont think this module is install on our server